# addEventListener() in Lua

Tags: iphone, ios, lua, execute, coronasdk

I have a problem when work with Corona and need a help.

When I register an event listener, such as `object:addEventListener("touch", listener)`. But listener function has many parameters like this:

```
function listener (event, param1, param2...)
    ...
end
```

My question is that how to pass all of parameters to listener. All search only pass one para is event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
local function listener(param1, param2)
        return function(event)
                print(event.name, event.phase, param1, param2)
        end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", listener(12, 33))
Runtime:addEventListener("tap", listener(55, 77))
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to just add properties to the object to which you attach the handler.  In the listener, you can access them through the `event.target` parameter.

e.g., adding new `param1` and `param2` properties to some image objects:

```
local touchHandler = function( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        local t = event.target
        print( "param1=" .. t.param1 .. ", param2=" .. t.param2 )
    end
end

local image1 = display.newImageRect( "myImage.png", 100, 100 )
image1.param1 = "Apple"
image1.param2 = "Zucchini"
image1:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )

local image2 = display.newImageRect( "myImage.png", 100, 100 )
image2.param1 = "AC/DC"
image2.param2 = "ZZ Top"
image2:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

This will print "Apple" and "Zucchini" when you touch image1, and print "AC/DC" and "ZZ Top" each time you touch image2.

Answer (score 0):

And you can add events to any lua table using the following class:

https://github.com/open768/library/blob/master/lib/lib-events.lua

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.