# Create event listener with parametrs Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need to create enterFrame listener with more parametrs than just event. I've read this:
[addEventListener() in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276127/addeventlistener-in-lua)
The first way, to use

```
local function listener(param1, param2)
     return function(event)
          print(event.name, event.phase, param1, param2)
     end
end    
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", listener(12, 33))
```

worked nice, but now I have a problem with deleting this enterFrame listener.

```
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",listener);
```

doesn't work because the function name is not "listener".
How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the functions you are creating, such that `listener(x, y)` will always return the same one. Something like this may work:

```
local listeners = {}
local function listener(param1, param2)
     -- add some separator, so 1,12 is different from 11,2
     local key = param1.."\1"..param2
     listeners[key] = listeners[key] or function(event)
          print(event.name, event.phase, param1, param2)
     end
     return listeners[key]
end
```

Since `listener(12, 33)` will always return the same result, now you can do `Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",listener(12,33))`